# Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Musical Practice & Performance Stack Exchange](http://music.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Woah. I found the evaluation when I went to the review page. Now, a month later, I read the directions. :)

Comment: @luserdroog These posts are linked from the instructions in the review queue. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What are Accidental Notes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10395/what-are-accidental-notes)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [scales on the guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10202/scales-on-the-guitar)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Create deep bass effect like Osmos for iPad soundtrack](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10246/create-deep-bass-effect-like-osmos-for-ipad-soundtrack)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Can all notes be produced using only the trumpet's valves?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/can-all-notes-be-produced-using-only-the-trumpets-valves)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Should the soloist watch the conductor?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/should-the-soloist-watch-the-conductor)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why are these notes separated on the stave?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10469/why-are-these-notes-separated-on-the-stave)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Guitar unusual buzzing](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/guitar-unusual-buzzing)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Passive and active pickups for bass guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10288/passive-and-active-pickups-for-bass-guitar)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Difference between Baritone and Euphonium](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10370/difference-between-baritone-and-euphonium)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Are kevlar straps on bass drum pedals reliable?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10376/are-kevlar-straps-on-bass-drum-pedals-reliable)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

Comment: Please explain the formula used to establish net score from excellent/satisfactory/needs improvement.

Comment: @Tim, yes.  And what scale it is out of?  1 being best?

Comment: @Tim: It's the number of "Excellent"s minus the number of "Needs Improvement"s.

Comment: Thanks, Ullallulloo. Still don't know what to make of the results, or how this improves things,though.